# patch lists for Redhat linux 5.9 -64 bit

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Can any one update the lists of kernel patches released for Linux 5.9 Redhat and what is the current patch level.

Thanks
Mohan

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `yum-plugin-changelog` plugin installed:

```
yum --releasever=5 list kernel --changelog
```

Answer (score 0):

Red Hat publish all security updates, bug fixes and product enhancements on https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/ and specifically for RHEL 5 on https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/rhel-server-errata.html

For systems properly registered with Red Hat or a Red Hat satellite server there are reporting features on which of those **Errata** are applicable to that specific system and from the command line you can list available updated **RPM packages** with

```
yum list available
```

Your current "patch level" would  be found in `/etc/redhat-release` and at the most basic `rpm -qa --last` will list all installed RPM packages by install date. [`yum history list`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Yum-Transaction_History.html) will also show you your patch history.

The changelog with applied CVE security updates of any installed RPM package can be queried with

```
rpm -q --changelog <package_name>
```